# getElementById innerHTML not work for me?

Tags: javascript

getElementById innerHTML not work for me ?

When user fill data in input tag, it's will be change data to `Hello!`

http://jsfiddle.net/59DFY/21/

```
<input type="text" id="hola" onchange="changeMe()">
<script>
function changeMe() {
  document.getElementById("hola").innerHTML="Hello!";
}
</script>
```

Comment: input fields have value not innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

Use **value** property of input text.

The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a text field.

The value property contains the default value OR the value a user types in (or a value set by a script).

So try to Change it like this

```
function changeMe() {
  document.getElementById("hola").value ="Hello!";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59DFY/21/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `value`. It will "change" the inner HTML on the input element, but that's not displayed on the screen since it's a void element. It does not technically have `innerHMTL` but browsers will do something like `<input ...>Hello!</input>`. The text for an `input` element uses `value` other than `innerHTML` that for example an `<p>` or `<div>` would use.

```
function changeMe() {
    document.getElementById("hola").value="Hello!"; 
}
```

Comment: "*It will change the inner HTML on the input element*" - no, it won't. The problem is specifically that the `<input />` element is a void, or replaced, element: it *has no inner HTML*, it cannot contain any child-nodes of any type.

Comment: @DavidThomas Actually it does. Changing inner HTML on a `input` would make it look like so: `<input ...>Hello!</input>`. But it's not displayed on the screen.

Comment: And the reason it doesn't display on the screen is because: "the <input /> element is a void, or replaced, element: it *has no inner HTML*, it cannot contain any child-nodes of any type." Assigning a property (`innerHTML`) doesn't confer any ability, or validity, to the solution you propose.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think I see what you mean, when I said "inner HTML" I wasn't talking about the property, but what the browser did. I've changed my answer so i'ts more clear.

Comment: @robert dewo it works if you see it by inspecting element.your code is correct.