# InnerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know similar questions have been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604299/what-is-innerhtml-on-input-elements) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580933/getelementbyid-innerhtml-not-work-for-me). But those don't exactly resemble my situation becase they are trying to change the value of an input box while I am trying to update the HTML of a `div` element. My issue is that I am calling a JS function right at the top of my HTML page and the function is meant to update the `innerHTML` of one of the `div` elements on the page. And for some reason this isn't working. According to an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849204/javascript-in-html-head-innerhtml-not-working), I understand that this could be because I am attempting to access the div even before the page has fully loaded. To resolve this, I tried calling the function from the subject div's `onload()` event. However, even this refuses to work.

```js
function wotd() {
  $('#wotd').HTML("<strong>test</strong>");
  alert($('#wotd').text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //wotd();
</script>

<div class="col col-md-4">
  <!-- WOTD panel -->
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-box card-effect">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-title">Word of the Day</div>
    <div id="wotd" class="panel-body panel-text" onload="wotd();">
      Word of the day not currently available.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div doesn't have an `onload` event, for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`innerHTML` is `javasript` property. You should use `html()` in `jquery` to replace the content of element. And also `div` does not have `onload` event. You should do it on `document ready` or `body load` like following.

```js
function wotd() {
    $('#wotd').html("<strong>test</strong>");
    alert($('#wotd').text());
}

wotd();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-box card-effect">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-title">Word of the Day</div>
    <div id="wotd" class="panel-body panel-text" onload="wotd();">
      Word of the day not currently available.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```